# Is there another javascript method than .Replace because it is not compatible with all androids

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, replace, vuejs2

As written in the title, I would look for another alternative javascript method to Replace to format an IBAN.
I am on a project and when I start to enter an IBAN like FR76 1 the text is duplicated but this problem is only present on old phones like my father's phone, it works fine on computer and with my phone.

```
 <template>
      <div class="form_container p-4">
          <b-field
            label="IBAN"
            custom-class="is-small has-text-weight-light has-text-grey"
            class="has-text-left has-text-weight-light"
          >
            <b-input rounded v-model.trim="formatedIBAN" placeholder="IBAN" />
          </b-field>
      </div>
    </template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import IBAN from 'iban';

@Component
export default class IbanTest extends Vue {
  public form: any = {
    iban: '',
  };

  get formatedIBAN(): string {
    return this.form.iban;
  }

  set formatedIBAN(iban: string) {
    this.form.iban = iban.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  }

}
</script>
```

it's really the replace method that causes this problem.
(But the problem occurs only on old versions of android in my opinion). 
If anyone has another idea for an alternative to the method thanks so much <3.

Edit: The problem reproduces this even on a pixel 6, I don't really understand where the problem comes from

Comment: Looking at this table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#browser_compatibility It looks like the support is Android 4.4 and looking at the stats, it's highly unlikely that there is something compatible with a 9 years old version. On top of it not being that popular nowadays: https://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/worldwide I guess the solution is to upgrade here.

Comment: If you meant not compatible with a browser (which is more likely), install another one: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replace

Comment: @kissu Precisely the problem is on chrome, opera, edge but only on android. on pc it works correctly on its different browsers

Comment: Setup a mobile debugger via chrome to get access to the console and see what is not working there exactly.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) claims compatibility with Chrome 1, Edge 12, Firefox 1, Opera 4, Safari 1, and Chrome Android 18

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
Basically I used a library to do it but this problem was present so I wanted to test by making a regex taken on internet.
Same problem, I say to myself that the problem is the replace, because without it 0 problem. 
The regex actually allows to put in capital letters and to separate by spaces every 4 characters I found it on internet. (it works correctly on pc)

Comment: There is no issue with the regexps here, both make perfect sense, the first one removes all chars other than alphanumeric ones (keeps only letters and digits) and the second inerts a space after each 4 chars. Quite typical, so it is not  a problem. If the special chars remain the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you have the same problem on your phone?

Comment: On my phone, I use Samsung Internet, and the special chars are removed once I type an alphanumeric char.